# How to group by ID column and select which row should be removed by a select number in R?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that looks something like this...

```
df1 <- structure(list(Pos = c("A2", "A3", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A22", "A23", 
    "C1", "C2", "C3", "C5", "C6", "C7"), GOIcp = c(5.49, 26.8, 26.83,                                                                       27.03, 26.78, 26.91, 26.65, 26.15, 22.93, 22.79, 22.76, 21.94, 
    21.67, 22.54, 23.15, 22.92, 26.25, 26.95, 26.82, 27.22, 29.25, 
    27.27), HKGcp = c(24.92, 25.71, 25.44, 25.53, 25.28, 25.97, 25.98, 
    25.6, 25.5, 25.42, 25.29, 24.54, 24.46, 25.21, 25.17, 25.02, 
    25.58, 25.99, 26.06, 25.55, 25.61, 25.71), ID = c("1_pDLS_Pdyn", 
    "1_pDLS_Pdyn", "16_pDLS_Pdyn", "16_pDLS_Pdyn", "16_pDLS_Pdyn", 
    "6_pDMS_Pdyn", "6_pDMS_Pdyn", "6_pDMS_Pdyn", "1_pDLS_Penk", "1_pDLS_Penk", "1_pDLS_Penk", "16_pDLS_Penk", "16_pDLS_Penk", "16_pDLS_Penk","6_pDMS_Penk", "6_pDMS_Penk", "2_pDLS_Pdyn", "2_pDLS_Pdyn", "2_pDLS_Pdyn", "17_pDLS_Pdyn", "17_pDLS_Pdyn", "17_pDLS_Pdyn")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-22L))
```

I want to group the function by the ID column. Then, looking at the grouped ID's I want to remove any rows in which the difference between the rows in the GOIcp column is greater than 1.5 for that ID. However, if all of the rows for that ID have a difference greater than 1.5 from each other, then keep the rows.

For a better explanation, row 1 and 2 would be kept because the it's only 2 rows and the points are far apart. But, the last 3 rows there is one data point for that ID that is greater than a difference of 1.5 from the other 2 rows. So, the 29.25 row should get deleted from the dataframe.

I hope this makes sense. And any help would be great!

I have tried doing some "for loops" to do this but aside from manually deleting the rows, I'm not sure how to go about this.

The output would look like this...

```
    Pos  GOIcp  HKGcp        ID
    A2   5.49   24.92   1_pDLS_Pdyn
    A3   26.80  25.71   1_pDLS_Pdyn
    A5   26.83  25.44   16_pDLS_Pdyn
    A6   27.03  25.53   16_pDLS_Pdyn
    A7   26.78  25.28   16_pDLS_Pdyn
    A9   26.91  25.97   6_pDMS_Pdyn
    A10  26.65  25.98   6_pDMS_Pdyn
    A11  26.15  25.60   6_pDMS_Pdyn
    A13  22.93  25.50   1_pDLS_Penk
    A14  22.79  25.42   1_pDLS_Penk
    A15  22.76  25.29   1_pDLS_Penk
    A17  21.94  24.54   16_pDLS_Penk
    A18  21.67  24.46   16_pDLS_Penk
    A19  22.54  25.21   16_pDLS_Penk
    A22  23.15  25.17   6_pDMS_Penk
    A23  22.92  25.02   6_pDMS_Penk
    C1   26.25  25.58   2_pDLS_Pdyn
    C2   26.95  25.99   2_pDLS_Pdyn
    C3   26.82  26.06   2_pDLS_Pdyn
    C5   27.22  25.55   17_pDLS_Pdyn
    C7   27.27  25.71   17_pDLS_Pdyn
```

I wish it were as simple as deleting the C6 row (regarding the Pos column) but take into consideration that this is a large dataframe and I only presented a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map_ df`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  split(., f = .$ID) %>% 
  map_df(~ {
    df <- . 
    df %>%
      add_count() %>% 
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(diff = min(abs(GOIcp - df[df[, "GOIcp"] != GOIcp, "GOIcp"]))) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      filter( (diff <= 1.5 & sum(diff > 1.5) != n) | sum(diff > 1.5) == n ) %>% 
      select(-n, -diff)
    }
  ) %>% 
  arrange(row) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 21 x 4
   Pos   GOIcp HKGcp ID          
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
 1 A2     5.49  24.9 1_pDLS_Pdyn 
 2 A3    26.8   25.7 1_pDLS_Pdyn 
 3 A5    26.8   25.4 16_pDLS_Pdyn
 4 A6    27.0   25.5 16_pDLS_Pdyn
 5 A7    26.8   25.3 16_pDLS_Pdyn
 6 A9    26.9   26.0 6_pDMS_Pdyn 
 7 A10   26.6   26.0 6_pDMS_Pdyn 
 8 A11   26.2   25.6 6_pDMS_Pdyn 
 9 A13   22.9   25.5 1_pDLS_Penk 
10 A14   22.8   25.4 1_pDLS_Penk 
11 A15   22.8   25.3 1_pDLS_Penk 
12 A17   21.9   24.5 16_pDLS_Penk
13 A18   21.7   24.5 16_pDLS_Penk
14 A19   22.5   25.2 16_pDLS_Penk
15 A22   23.2   25.2 6_pDMS_Penk 
16 A23   22.9   25.0 6_pDMS_Penk 
17 C1    26.2   25.6 2_pDLS_Pdyn 
18 C2    27.0   26.0 2_pDLS_Pdyn 
19 C3    26.8   26.1 2_pDLS_Pdyn 
20 C5    27.2   25.6 17_pDLS_Pdyn
21 C7    27.3   25.7 17_pDLS_Pdyn
```

So what are we doing here: First we `split` the data.frame by `ID` into a list of data.frames.

Using `map_df` we apply a custom function on each of those data.frames. For every row we calculate the difference to every other GOIcp, taking the minimum of all distances. If this difference is less than 1.5 the row is kept. If all differences in a data.frame are greater than 1.5, they are all kept.
Finally we bind those data.frame back into one data.frame.

The same way without using `purrr`

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  group_map(~ {
    df <- . 
    df %>%
      add_count() %>% 
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(diff = min(abs(GOIcp - df[df[, "GOIcp"] != GOIcp, "GOIcp"]))) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      filter( (diff <= 1.5 & sum(diff > 1.5) != n) | sum(diff > 1.5) == n ) %>% 
      select(-n, -diff)
  }
  ) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  arrange(row) %>% 
  select(-row)
```

Comment: That works great, thank you! What needs to be changed if I want to remove rows of the same ID if they are different...instead of keeping them? For example , get rid of rows 1 and 2.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking for... Perhaps removing the `sum(diff > 1.5) == n` part?

Comment: Ah, yes! That did it. Thank you